# Gauss Law Difference between Griffiths and Jackson

Tags: electromagnetism

As per Jackson, Gauss's Law is defined as:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E=4 \pi \rho/\epsilon$$

Now as per Griffiths, the same equation is defined as:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E= \rho/\epsilon$$

So the $\pi$ part is missing in Griffiths, which is written in SI unit. Is this difference due to that Jackson is written in CGS whereas Griffiths is in SI??

Comment: I take it you ignored Jackson's footnote on page three to read the whole Appendix devoted to literally this question?

Comment: @KyleKanos and for that matter Griffith's "Advertisement" page that leads to Appendix C on units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the pi part is missing is Griffith which is written in SI unit. Is this difference due to that Jackson is written in CGS whereas Griffith in SI??

Yes.

Further comment: there are also some newer editions of Jackson's book in SI. Also to be more precise the original Jackson's book uses [cgs-gauss units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units).

Comment: Yes but Jackson's heart wasn't in it for SI: he reverted to cgs as soon as it got more difficult!